# Drag and drop into sandboxed App

Tags: cocoa, permissions, appstore-sandbox

I have an application that needs to save a file in the same location as the source file drag on the window of the application. The sandbox does not let me even right after you have checked "User selected File" ....

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When dropping a file to your App, sandbox grants only access to this file. You can't even rename it. To write a new file in the same directory, use an NSOpenPanel to get write access to the directory.

eg:

```
 - (void)showGrantAccessForFolderOfFile:(NSURL *)urlOfFile
 {
    NSURL *urlToGrant = [urlOfFile URLByDeletingLastPathComponent];
    NSOpenPanel *openPanel = [NSOpenPanel openPanel];
    [openPanel setAllowsMultipleSelection:NO];
    [openPanel setCanChooseDirectories:YES];
    [openPanel setCanChooseFiles:NO];
    [openPanel setCanCreateDirectories:NO];
    [openPanel setDirectoryURL:urlToGrant];

    [openPanel setTitle:@"Grant Access To Folder"];
    [openPanel setMessage:@"Please grant access to the file’s folder"];
    [openPanel setPrompt:@"Grant Access"];

    // then run the panel as in documentation and handle errors
    // could also set a delegate and grey out other directories
    // store the sandboxed to access it later again
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it's works great... But is there a way to record the path in the application preferences and don't open an OpenPanel every time you launch the application ?

Comment: This is a completely new question. See either documentation here: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Security/Conceptual/AppSandboxDesignGuide/AppSandboxInDepth/AppSandboxInDepth.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011183-CH3-SW16  "Security-Scoped Bookmarks and Persistent Resource Access" or search on StackOverflow for this.

Answer (score 2):

Have you checked Apple's docs, in particular the **[Drag and Drop Programming Topics](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/DragandDrop/Tasks/DraggingFiles.html)** ?

> **Important:** Although you can support dragging file paths, in general, you should avoid doing so unless you are certain that the
>   destination app will never be run in an app sandbox. If you use an
>   NSString, OS X has no way to know whether that string should be
>   interpreted as a path; thus, OS X does not expand the destination
>   app’s sandbox to allow access to the file or directory at that
>   location.
>
> Instead, use an NSURL, a bookmark, or a filename pasteboard type.

Comment: I saw that in OSX 10.9, after a drag and drop operation is finished, the sandbox only gives me read access to the dragged directory, even if I registered the view for `NSURLPboardType` dragged type.